# Android studio showing error,gradle file,please find the solution,it shwing some find of error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I sync my project in Android Studio, I got this error

> ERROR: Cause: https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-3.4.2-all.zip

Comment: Simple, the specified gradle zip file does not exist. Make sure you're using the correct version

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added wrong dependency package.

So Go to gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties and checkout your "distributionUrl" has the correct value or not.

You have added a wrong package gradle-3.4.2-all.zip. try changing it to gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

I hope this helps.

Comment: But sir why we change the version to 4.10.2??

Comment: visit this link https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and find out gradle-3.4.2-all.zip this package if you can. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse **gradle** with the **Android Gradle plugin**.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

It is the **Android Gradle plugin**.
[Check the release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) for other versions.

The **gradle version** is defined in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.
Use:

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```